# Android API selection for my app

Tags: android, api

I'm building my first android app and slightly confused when choosing the right API. I've noticed that some functions are available starting from API 21. But then, **why in the world would anyone use API 21 or higher if it's only supported by 40.5%** of android devices??? Only 4 out of 10 sounds ridiculous to me. Or, is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: so that developers can provide them extra features, better app experience who are using.

Comment: You'll want to use a new API version if and when it provides features which you want to leverage and which are not available or broken in previous versions. Hence, you should go for the lowest API version which supports all the features you need to achieve maximum compatibility.

Comment: Additionally, you can expect the numbers to change in the future so that, in a year or so, the majority of devices will be v21+.

Comment: Well, I understand all that "Upgrade dynamics" to move one. But leaving more that 60% devices out is insane. With iOS it's just 25% at the most.

Answer (score 0):

Well it actually depends on you as a developer to know your target audience, and choose the right API target. Nevertheless, all these new features and functionalities that you think are only available for new APIs all have support through the use of Android Support Library. You can still have access to all the newer APIs through support libraries officially provided by android. 
[Android Support Library](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiY8u_UlPnTAhWpD8AKHc8kDJ8QFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftopic%2Flibraries%2Fsupport-library%2Findex.html&usg=AFQjCNGq4jdw63aItZ0oEQ1JptwIZcJ4-g&sig2=KU7187zWL7VP11Vxv4eTYw)

At the end of the day you would want to target as many devices as possible to get a wider audience for your app.

Answer (score 0):

now **google research on the android "O"**. so its very soon new android application development API coming but you are say that you create your first android application so you need to fist familiar with all api so for you batter is you use **minimum 16** and **maximum 23** or **24** what ever you chose.if you chose latest api's so that u have latest android studio version.

for you all name and api [details](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers)